# java get getter/setter name from property name

Tags: java, api, getter, setter

I have some like this:

```
String getterName = "get"+StringUtils.capitalize(propertyName);
Method methodLabel = item.getClass().getMethod(getterName);
```

I know that this does not always work because properties like: "X" "x" etc... are diferent rules.

¿is there a method in the JAVA API to pass name property to getter/setter name ?

I don't want to use: PropertyDescriptor. It requires to work both setter and getter.

EDIT:

What I want is this:

```
String propertyName ="money";
String getterPropertyNameByConventionJava = ConvertPropertyNameToGetterName(propertyName);
System.out.println(getterPropertyNameByConventionJava);
//prints getMoney or getMoney() anyway.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own solution since I see that there is not official implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("get"+cuerpoGetterSetter("probando0"));
        System.out.println("get"+cuerpoGetterSetter("x"));
        System.out.println("get"+cuerpoGetterSetter("X"));
        System.out.println("get"+cuerpoGetterSetter("URL"));
        System.out.println("get"+cuerpoGetterSetter("xIndex"));
    }
    public static String cuerpoGetterSetter(String propiedad) {
        if (propiedad == null || propiedad.length() == 0) {
            return propiedad;
        }
        if (propiedad.length() == 1) {
            return propiedad.toUpperCase();
        }
        if (Character.isUpperCase(propiedad.charAt(0))) {
            return propiedad;
        }
        if (propiedad.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(propiedad.charAt(1))) {
            return propiedad;
        }
        return propiedad.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propiedad.substring(1, propiedad.length());
    }
```

Results:

```
getProbando0
getX
getX
getURL
getxIndex
```

Comment: I agree with Stultuske's comments above. However it might be instructive to look at java.beans.Introspector (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html) - this is about Java's standard way to get from getter/setter to a property name, i.e. the other way to what you are doing.

Comment: where is in that api the solution to get name convention getter from name property ?

Comment: It only gets the name property given a class with get... and/or set... methods. What I meant was: if your code is making the method names from a property name, it would be best if your code was consistent with the Javabeans way of doing it. Source code is here https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/beans/Introspector.java but it's a long read, probably not worth it!